# How to use "Date" & "Autofilter" by UK date style in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, autofilter

I wrote Excel VBA for copying & paste data from one file to another file.

I created input box to ask user to input start date & end date, then use "autofilter" function & copy & paste. However, I used UK date style (dd/mm/yyyy) is not working. I had to input US date style(mm/dd/yyyy) instead.

Is there any way to allow UK date style in my VBA?

```
Sub MyFilter()
    
'define startdate & enddate & create msgbox
    Dim W1Startdate As Date, W1Enddate As Date
    Columns("A:A").Select
  
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    
    Range("A2").Select
    
    W1Startdate = Application.InputBox("Enter the Start Date in MM/DD/YYYY format")
    W1Enddate = Application.InputBox("Enter the End Date in MM/DD/YYYY format")
    
   
     
' base on startdate & end date to filter Column A
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E35").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & W1Startdate, Criteria2:="<=" & W1Enddate
   
' select & copy filtered column A information
   With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy
   
   End With

' Paste filter column A to target file ("list2.xlsx") *change target file name when needed
    Windows("list2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("MASTER.xlsm").Activate
    
 ' select & copy filtered column B information
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy
    
    End With
   
 ' Paste filter column B to target file ("list2.xlsx") *change target file name when needed
    Windows("list2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("MASTER.xlsm").Activate
   
 ' select & copy filtered column 3 information
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    .Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy
    
    End With
   
 ' Paste filter column C to target file ("list2.xlsx") *change target file name when needed
    Windows("list2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("MASTER.xlsm").Activate
   
 ' select & copy filtered column 3 information
    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    .Offset(1, 4).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy
    
    End With
   
 ' Paste filter column E to target file ("list2.xlsx") *change target file name when needed
    Windows("list2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("MASTER.xlsm").Activate
   
   
   
End Sub
```

I expect I can enter UK date format to achieve the result.

Comment: *Is there any way to allow UK date style in my VBA?* split the input as string into parts and use DateSerial.`ar=Split(s,"/"): dt = DateSerial(ar(2),ar(1),ar(0))`

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E35").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(W1Startdate), Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(W1Enddate)` should work by turning your date into a number.